# Xamarin Shell Login page stays in memory

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, memory-leaks

I used login example here: https://github.com/davidortinau/ShellLoginSample

With shell looks like:

```
<ShellItem Route="login">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}"/>
</ShellItem>

<TabBar Route="main">
    <Tab Title="Browse" Icon="tab_feed.png">
        <ShellContent 
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png">
        <ShellContent 
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Admin" IsVisible="{Binding IsAdmin}">
        <ShellContent
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AdminPage}"/>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

Where initially at the start of the app user is navigated to LoginPage
And then from login page is navigated to MainPage (ItemsPage).

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//main");
```

I added additional logic to ItemsPage where I force GC.
With button on ItemsPage

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>{
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        });
    }
```

But from xamarin profiler I can see that LoginPage stays in memory. Should it be collected by GC?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I can't make sure if you force GC successfully or not. You can refert to [this code about GC](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15348#issuecomment-1125449256) in the issue about [[BUG] Xamarin Shell Navigation Memory leak](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15348).

In addition, I check the code in the sample you provided and I found the it used the MessangeCenter in the LoginPage. Even though the MessagingCenter class uses weak references and allow them to be garbage collected.

But as [this comment about the messagecenter said](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11476#issuecomment-662174774), it will not get gc when you called `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//main");` at once. And the LoginPage is a publisher in the MessageCenter, I can't make sure it should be recycled or not. You can refer to the issue about [Pages created by Shell.Current.GoToAsync are not re-used or disposed](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11476).

But you can try to remove the code about messagecenter and them used the code about force GC in the link and test again.

Comment: Thanks for your response. @Liyun Zhang - MSFT
I edited post (added logic how I force GC).

According to your suggestions, I removed all references of the MessageCenter from whole code and additionally I increased nuggets for Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin to be the latests.
But I can still see LoginPage  in profiler as a live object. Do you have any other suggestions what I can try?

Comment: When you get back to the loginpage from the main, is there still only one instance of it? @MilanHenkrich

Comment: There is always only one instance, it is not growing up.

Comment: So it's not memory leak. The cause may be the appshell has the reference of it or some other cause. Don't worry about this.@MilanHenkrich

Comment: And when you navigate between the pages. There is a [previous property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.shellnavigatedeventargs.previous?view=xamarin-forms#xamarin-forms-shellnavigatedeventargs-previous) in the [Shell.Navigated Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.shell.navigated?view=xamarin-forms). It may have the reference of the loginpage. So you can go to a third page or forth page and then force gc to check if the loginpage is still in the memory or not. @MilanHenkrich

Comment: So I added multiple pages (5 in total ) and I navigate through them in cascade via  await Navigation.PushAsync((new NewPageX()));

When I get to the last one I manually trigger GC multiple times. But LoginPage is still in memory. 

I understand that it is not memory leak, but I would like to get rid of this LoginPage. Is there a way how I can find what reference is causing it via profiler?

Comment: So for that I don't know if there is a way to find the reference. But the cause in your project may be the login page registered in the appshell. You can remove it from the appshell and use the MainPage = New LoginPage(), MainPage = New AppShell() to navigate. And then you can check if the loginpage is still in the memory. @MilanHenkrich

Comment: Thanks this helped. I can confirm that LoginPage is not anymore in memory.
But now I noticed that these NewPageX (that I created according your suggestion) are in memory when I navigate back to MainPage and I trigger GC few times..

They are just blank pages only with one Label as content and        
 <ToolbarItem Text="NexPage" Clicked="Next_Clicked" />. Not sure why they are not GC collected.

Comment: Did you register their route in the appshell? @MilanHenkrich